# Is there any way I can get notified when user trigger the system default long press behavior in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I know how to disable system default long press behavior by evaluate this script `document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none'`.

There's such a requirement. When users long press an image and click the "save to album" popup button, I need to be notified and give a response.

Is there any good way (not a hack) I can achieve this?

Or I should make a custom native interface and disable the default long press behavior?

Comment: whats your question ? you want to show that popup or not ?

Comment: I want to know when the menu poped up and when the user did click those buttons. @ShauketSheikh

Comment: I have not tried my self, but you can try to add observer on your class for this specific class UIMenuController and catch popup